# K8s app installed using Helm does not show up in Helm list table

Tags: kubernetes, namespaces, kubernetes-helm

I'm trying to learn Helm using a simple nginx chart that creates a single pod and service.

I want to install this into a specified namespace (dev in this case).

My chart comprises x2 templates, x1 for the deployment to create the pod, and x1 for a service to map a port to the container.

**deployment.yaml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ include "nginx.fullname" . }}
  namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace | quote }}
  labels:
    {{- include "nginx.labels" . | nindent 4 }}
spec:
  replicas: {{ .Values.replicaCount | default 1 }}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      {{- include "nginx.selectorLabels" . | nindent 6 }}
  template:
    metadata:
      {{- with .Values.podAnnotations }}
      annotations:
        {{- toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
      {{- end }}
      labels:
        {{- include "nginx.selectorLabels" . | nindent 8 }}
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
          securityContext:
            {{- toYaml .Values.securityContext | nindent 12 }}
          image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag | default .Chart.AppVersion }}"
          imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.image.pullPolicy }}
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: {{ .Values.service.containerport }}
              protocol: TCP
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /
              port: http
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /
              port: http
```

**service.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: {{ include "nginx.fullname" . }}
  namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace | quote }}
  labels:
    {{- include "nginx.labels" . | nindent 4 }}
spec:
  type: {{ .Values.service.type }}
  ports:
    - port: {{ .Values.service.port }}
      nodePort:  {{ .Values.service.nodePort }}
      protocol: TCP
      name: http
  selector:
    {{- include "nginx.selectorLabels" . | nindent 4 }}
```

And the values file looks like this:

**values-dev.yaml**

```
replicaCount: 1

image:
  repository: nginx
  pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
  # Overrides the image tag whose default is the chart appVersion.
  tag: ""

service:
  type: NodePort
  containerport: 80
  port: 80
  nodePort: 31010

resources:
  limits:
    memory: 256Mi
    cpu: "250m"
  requests:
    memory: 128Mi
    cpu: "80m"
```

When I run my Helm command:

`helm install dev-nginx ./ --namespace dev --create-namespace --values values-dev.yaml`

Helm does seem to be installing everything required into the right namespace.

```
NAME: dev-nginx
LAST DEPLOYED: Wed Jun 14 18:22:03 2023
NAMESPACE: dev
STATUS: deployed
REVISION: 1
TEST SUITE: None
```

But when I run a `helm list` the installation does not show up in the table.

```
helm list
NAME    NAMESPACE   REVISION    UPDATED STATUS  CHART   APP VERSION
```

I can see everything if I verify using `kubectl`.

```
k get all -n dev
NAME                             READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/dev-nginx-5bff4b9659-mxmrb   1/1     Running   0          2m27s

NAME                TYPE       CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
service/dev-nginx   NodePort   10.109.251.249   <none>        80:31010/TCP   2m27s

NAME                        READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/dev-nginx   1/1     1            1           2m27s

NAME                                   DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/dev-nginx-5bff4b9659   1         1         1       2m27s
```

If I don't try to control the namespace and allow Helm to deploy into the 'default' namespace, the install shows up in the `helm install` table.

Is using Helm to install to a custom namespace possible and I am just making a mistake?

Many thanks

Comment: use `helm list -n dev` to show installations in dev namespace or `helm list -A` for all namespaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `helm list` command will give you the installed helm chart in the `default` namespace and you installed it in `dev` namespace.

Just run `helm list -n dev` to show installations in dev namespace or `helm list -A` for all namespaces.